# State-dependent event processing with state updates

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I want to use FRP (i.e., reactive banana 0.6.0.0) for [my project](https://github.com/copton/ocram) (a [GDB/MI](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html) front-end). But I have troubles declaring the event network.

There are commands from the GUI and there are stop events from GDB. Both need to be handled and handling them depends on the state of the system.

My current approach looks like this (I think this is the minimum required complexity to show the problem):

```
data Command = CommandA | CommandB
data Stopped = ReasonA  | ReasonB
data State = State {stateExec :: Exec, stateFoo :: Int}
data StateExec = Running | Stopped

create_network :: NetworkDescription t (Command -> IO ())
create_network = do
    (eCommand, fCommand) <- newEvent
    (eStopped, fStopped) <- newEvent
    (eStateUpdate, fStateUpdate) <- newEvent

    gdb <- liftIO $ gdb_init fStopped

    let
      eState = accumE initialState eStateUpdate
      bState = stepper initialState eState

    reactimate $ (handleCommand gdb fStateUpdate <$> bState) <@> eCommand
    reactimate $ (handleStopped gdb fStateUpdate <$> bState) <@> eStopped

    return fCommand
```

`handleCommand` and `handelStopped` react on commands and stop events depending on the current state. Possible reactions are calling (synchronous) GDB I/O functions and firing state update events. For example:

```
handleCommand :: GDB -> ((State -> State) -> IO ()) -> State -> Command -> IO ()
handleCommand gdb fStateUpdate state CommandA = case stateExec state of
   Running -> do
     gdb_interrupt gdb
     fStateUpdate f
 where f state' = state' {stateFoo = 23}
```

The problem is, when `f` gets evaluated by `accumE`, `state'` sometimes is different from `state`.

I am not 100% sure why this can happen as I don't fully understand the semantics of time and simultaneity and the order of "reactimation" in reactive banana. But I guess that state update functions fired by `handleStopped` might get evaluated before `f` thus changing the state.

Anyway, this event network leads to inconsistent state because the assumptions of `f` on the "current" state are sometimes wrong.

I have been trying to solve this problem for over a week now and I just cannot figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be a dangling parenthesis in your last line. `where f state' ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to make a `eStateUpdate` event occur whenever `eStop` or `eCommand` occurs?

If so, you can simply express it as the union of the two events:

```
let        
    eStateUpdate = union (handleCommand' <$> eCommand)
                         (handleStopped' <$> eStopped)

    handleCommand' :: Command -> (State -> State)
    handleStopped' :: Stopped -> (State -> State)

    eState = accumE initialState eStateUpdate

    etc.
```

Remember: events behave like ordinary values which you can combine to make new ones, you're not writing a chain of callback functions.

The `newEvent` function should only be used if you want to import an event from the outside world. That's the case for `eCommand` and `eStopped`, as they are triggered by the external GDB, but the `eStateUpdate` event seems to be internal to the network.

---

Concerning behavior of your current code, reactive-banana always does the following things when receiving an external event:

1. Calculate/update all event occurrences and behavior values.
2. Run the `reactimate`s in order.

But it may well happen happen that step 2 triggers the network again (for instance via the `fStateUpdate` function), in which case the network calculates new values and calls the `reactimate`s again, *as part of this function call*. After this, flow control returns to the first sequence of `reactimates` that is still being run, and a second call to `fStateUpdate` will have strange effects: the behaviors inside the network have been updated already, but the argument to this call is still an old value. Something like this:

```
reactimate1
reactimate2
    fStateUpdate      -- behaviors inside network get new values
        reactimate1'
        reactimate2'
reactimate3           -- may contain old values from first run!
```

Apparently, this is tricky to explain and tricky to reason about, but fortunately unnecessary if you stick to the guidelines above.

---

In a sense, the latter part embodies the trickiness of writing event handlers in the traditional style, whereas the former part embodies the (relative) simplicity of programming with events in FRP-style.

The golden rule is:

*Do not call another event handler while handling an event.*

You don't have to follow this rule, and it can be useful at times; but things will become complicated if you do that.

Comment: Heinrich, thank you for helping me. I understand your guidelines but I don't see how to apply them in my case because `handleCommand` needs to perform IO actions. For example, in order to handle an interrupt command from the GUI `handleCommand` needs to call `gdb_interrupt` first and then `gdb_backtrace` to see where the execution got interrupted. This information is then required to update the state accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I see. IO actions are problematic, as usual. The important thing that I want to point out here is that once you deal with IO actions, you will soon run into problems of ordering, regardless of whether you employ FRP or not. For instance, it is conceivable that the `gdb_backtrace` function generates another event and then the question is: do you update the state before handling it or after handling it, or do you handle it at all?

Comment: However, if I understand that correctly, `gdb_backtrace` is essentially a pure operation that just queries the internal state of the debugger, and hence should be safe to call at any time. You're probably looking for a function `unsafeMapIO :: Event t (IO a) -> Event t a`, but reactive-banana doesn't currently support that and I'm not entirely sure whether it is really a good idea.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a ready-made answer for your impedance mismatch between FRP/pure and GDB/IO. However, I have a hunch that making the internal state of the GDB debugger explicit as a `Behavior DebuggerState` may help a lot; in particular, you can perform arbitrary of IO actions from inside an `AddHandler` and use `fromChanges` to get the debugger state.

Comment: Thank you, Heinrich. Good to know that it's indeed the nature of the problem that makes things complex. I am not sure either, what feature would help as I am not familiar with FRP yet. I will answer to this question once I found a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, FRP seems not to be the right abstraction for my problem.

So I switched to actors with messages of type  `State -> IO State`.

This gives me the required serialization of events and the possibility to do IO when updating the state. What I loose is the nice description of the event network. But it's not too bad with actors either.